# R Shiny app seems to hang when generating data

Tags: r, shiny

Colleagues,

I'm creating a Shiny app that can generate a data set with user-defined properties. The intended data-generation function can take some time, so I've substituted a very simple one.

My problem is that the app seems to just hang, or nothing happens at all, when I hit the GO button.

**DEBUG** in *Rstudio* shows nothing, and **reactlog** also gives no information.
Similar questions on this stack**overflow** forum are more than 8 years old, and suggestions don't seem to work either.

I'm sure the solution is head-slapping simple but, right now, I'm lost.

Any suggestions from those more knowledgeable than this *Shiny* newbie?

```
## generate data set with user-defined parameters

## load libraries
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)

##

options(shiny.reactlog = TRUE)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Synthesise data"),

  # Sidebar
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      ## Sample size
      numericInput("sample_n", "Sample size", 30,
        min = 10, max = 300, step = 1
      ),
      h4("Desired scale moments"),
      numericInput("target_mean", "Target mean", 4),
      numericInput("target_sd", "Target st dev", 1),
      hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #000000;"),
      actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
      actionButton("goChart", "show chart"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h4("generated data"),
      # table of generated data
      DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),
      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      plotOutput("resultPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  mytable <- reactive(input$goButton, {
    ## substituting data-gen function that can take some time
    mydata <- rnorm(sample_n, target_mean, target_sd) |>
      data.frame()
    colnames(mydata) <- "scale"

    # saveRDS(mydata, file = "generatedData.RDS")

    output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
      mydata
    }))
  })

  myplot <- eventReactive(input$goChart, {
    output$resultPlot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mydata, aes(x = scale)) +
        geom_density()
    })
  })
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Few code errors here :

- forgot `input$` when using `sample_n`, `target_mean` and `target_sd` in server
- put some `output` definition inside `eventReactive` or `reactive` is a terrible habit
- `reactive` is not used like you did. `EventReactive` is what you needed here.

Here is a corrected version of you code

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Synthesise data"),
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
            numericInput("sample_n", "Sample size", 30,
                   min = 10, max = 300, step = 1
      ),
      h4("Desired scale moments"),
      numericInput("target_mean", "Target mean", 4),
      numericInput("target_sd", "Target st dev", 1),
      hr(style = "border-top: 1px solid #000000;"),
      actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
      actionButton("goChart", "show chart"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h4("generated data"),
      DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),
      plotOutput("resultPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  mydata <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    mydata <- data.frame(scale = rnorm(input$sample_n, input$target_mean, input$target_sd))
    return(mydata)
  })
  
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(
    mydata()
  ))

  output$resultPlot <- renderPlot({
    input$goChart
    isolate(ggplot(mydata(), aes(x = scale)) +
        geom_density())
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```